# Problemas com url amigavel no codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, htaccess, url

Estou com o seguinte problema.

Estou trabalhando com um sistema em CodeIgniter e preciso remover o index.php da url.

Meu .htaccess esta como abaixo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

O index.php em si já consegui resolver. O problema eh que o sistema tem um plugin de linguagens e a configuração do link é como abaixo:

```
www.site.com.br/pt/controller
```

A questão é que esse htacces esta sobrescrevendo o pt e eu não posso remover esse pt. E no caso, vão ter outras linguagens como en, es e etc.

Como resolve isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a linha

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

para

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s]+)[\/]?(.+)?$ index.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)?$ index.php?1=$1&2=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]{1,})?$ index.php?1=$1 [NC,L]
```

depois para acessar o pt da URL você pode usar:

```
$_GET['1']
```

e assim por diante.

Comment: vlw cara.... funcionou aqui... brigadão